# accepting acents in regex android

Tags: android, regex, diacritics

mates...

I am having troubles to pass through a regex accepting accents in android... All the things we have try like for java is not working properly, and android don't want our accented vocals ..

I have the following regex:

> Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+");

Any tip of how to include ñ and accents vocals in android?

Thanks very much in advance...

Here is our validation function:

```
public static boolean validarNombres(String nameToValidate){
byte step = 1;
byte minWords = 2;
byte maxWords = 5;
boolean validName = false;
String[] aux;

Matcher matcher = null;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+");

aux = nameToValidate.split(" ");

//PASO 2: check that the name has from 2 to 5 words
if(aux.length >= minWords && aux.length <= maxWords){
step++;
matcher = pattern.matcher(nameToValidate);
}

//PASO 3: check that the name matches out regex
if(step==2 && matcher.matches()){
validName = true;
}

return validName;
}
```

EDIT: Think found the mistake... We are not including the blank space bettwen the first and second name ... It works fine when we check just a word, but not for the full name... now....
Whats the code to include a blank space on our regex?, please

Thanks very much

Comment: Tried `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+");`?

Comment: Just done it... not working ... :(

Comment: Provide the whole relevant piece of code. The issue is not with the regex here. Explain what you mean by "not working".

Comment: Yes.. 2 to 5 words .. for a full name like: Miguel Angel de la Torre ... But this last regex is not working ... we will check word by word in the String array... Thanks very much Wiktor for the solution..

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate a string consisting of 2 to 5 words separated with whitespace(s), you may use

```
public static boolean validarNombres(String nameToValidate) { 
    return nameToValidate.matches("[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+(?:\\s[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+){1,4}");
}
```

The regex is anchored by default when used with the `.matches()` method, no need adding `^` and `$`.

**Pattern details**:

- `[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+` - 1 or more letters or/and diacritics
- `(?:\\s[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+){1,4}` - 1 to 4 (so, 2 to 5 in total) sequences of:

  - `\\s` - a single whitespace
  - `[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+`  - 1 or more letters or/and diacritics

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VT1Pe2/1).

Comment: Great job! .. now its working perfectly  .. thank you very mucha again